# How to award bounty on a dupe question?

Tags: support, specific-question, duplicates, bounty

I asked [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/116008/confront-the-manager-in-a-constructive-safe-manner-about-lack-of-work) as an anonymous user (as can be seen).
Now I want to reward [Ertai87](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/88183/ertai87) for his answer that acted like a clear wake up call to me.

However, the question was (incorrectly) flagged as a duplicate after another question and I can't see where is the "start a bounty" button. I think it's because the question is closed but I'm not sure.

Is there anyway I can still award a bounty on that question?

Comment: The post is now open again, if you wish to place your bounty :)

Comment: I don't think you have enough rep to place a bounty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there anyway I can still award a bounty on that question?

No, I'm afraid not. Closed questions cannot receive a bounty.

Unfortunately the [help page](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) doesn't specify this.

Comment: I understand that you answered in a more general way but I just figured out I can attempt at reopening that question, so there's still hope. (I'll accept as soon as the grace period ends)

Comment: @user90357 Yes, you can get the question reopened and place the bounty then. I didn't mention it because that's not really why you should try to reopen a question. You should do so if you think the close reason isn't justified or you've updated the question. Wanting to award a bounty makes reopening even more problematic since if you place a bounty on it right after its reopened, other users will *not* be able to close it again as long as your bounty remains up. That said, don't let it stop you from making bona fide edits to your question to make it stand on its own and deserves reopening.

Answer (score 3):

> However, the question was (incorrectly) flagged as a duplicate after another question

To expand Lilienthal's comment (and give it a little more visibility): If you believe the question was incorrectly closed, make a meta post with the tag [reopen-request](/questions/tagged/reopen-request) and explain why you think the question should be reopened.

You will either convince the community and the question will get reopened, or you will receive a better explanation of why the question was closed. In the latter case, you will have more information to work with while editing your question, if you choose to do so.

Comment: The post already has 4 reopen votes.